# Javascript closure: Inconsistent reuse of variable

Tags: javascript, closures

1) Why is there this inconsistency in JavaScript - I was expecting the fourth line to return 11 as well:

```
(function(n, m) { n = n + m; return n })(3, 8)                         == 11
(function(n, m) { var n = n + m; return n })(3, 8)                     == 11

(function(n) { return function(m) { n = n + m; return n } })(3)(8)     == 11
(function(n) { return function(m) { var n = n + m; return n } })(3)(8) == NaN
```

2) I'm writing a compiler of a language to javascript. I use `var` to avoid polluting the global space with temporary variables. It just happened above that my temporary variable was `n` and the overriding was fine.
Is there another way so that I can (re)define `n` such that if n was not defined previously, it still considers that `n` is local?

The following two variants pollute the namespace with `tmp`, which I want to avoid:

```
(function(n, m) { tmp = n + m; return tmp })(3, 8)                     == 11
(function(n) { return function(m) { tmp = n + m; return tmp } })(3)(8) == 11
```

Comment: Use `var tmp = n + m;`. It's the redeclaration of `n` (reusing the same variable name) that is causing you problems, because in that scope `n` is used before it is assigned a value so it has the value `undefined` and you get `var n = undefined + 8;`, which evaluates to `NaN`.

Comment: When you declare `n` in a smaller scope and there is already an `n` in a higher scope, the local `n` hides that higher scoped `n`, so references to it (without initializing it first) return `undefined`.

Answer (score 10):

In your fourth example:

```
(function(n) { return function(m) { var n = n + m; return n } })(3)(8) // == NaN
```

...you've **shadowed** the `n` parameter of the outer function with a local declaration. Since you haven't given that local variable any initializer, its default value is `undefined`. `undefined` plus any number is `NaN`.

You may be wondering why this is different from your second example:

```
(function(n, m) { var n = n + m; return n })(3, 8) // == 11
```

The answer is *scope*. In the second example, the `var n` appears in the scope where the `n` parameter already exists, and so does not shadow it (using `var` with the same identifier as a parameter in the same scope is a no-op). But in the fourth example, the `var n` appears in a *nested* scope under the one where the parameter `n` exists. And so it shadows the parent `n`.

Here, the `var` doesn't do anything, because there's already an `n` in-scope:

```js
function foo(n) {
    var n;
    console.log(n);
}
foo(42); // 42
```

But here, it does:

```js
function foo(n) {
    (function() {
        var n;
        console.log(n);
    })();
}
foo(42); // undefined
```

...because the parameter and the `var` are in different scopes.

> The following two variants pollute the namespace with tmp, which I want to avoid

No need for `tmp` (although a *local* `tmp` would be fine). If you want a nested function, just don't use `var` on `n`:

```js
console.log(
    (function(n) { return function(m) { n = n + m; return n } })(3)(8) // == NaN
);
```

That said, a **local** `tmp` (using `var`) would be no bad thing:

```js
console.log(
    (function(n) { return function(m) {
        var tmp = n + m;
        return tmp;
    }})(3)(8) // == 11
);
```

...but you have to declare it. Without the `var` declaring it, the code falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)*, which you do indeed want to avoid. :-)

---

* *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

Answer (score -1):

By placing `var` in front of `n` in the inner function, you're declaring a new `n` variable, which at that point is `undefined` and the reason you're getting `NaN` (e.g. `undefined` + 8 = `NaN`).

There's no need to declare a new variable. Just return the value:

```
(function(n) {
  return function(m) {
    return n + m;
  }
})(3)(8)
```

Comment: My example is just a toy case. I need to define a temporary variable. The code is much more complex than what I described.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer Then give it a different name from the variable in the outer scope that you want to reference.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer: We can only help you with what we see. :-) But fundamentally, if you want to use an identifier from an outer scope, don't redefine it in an inner scope.